# AWS CloudFront Returns Access Denied from S3 Origin after adding *=utf-8'' in response-content-disposition

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

Currently my signed URLs all look like below and they work fine:

`https://cloudfront/filekey?response-content-disposition=inline%3Bfilename%3D{utf-8-encoded-filename.pdf}&Expires=...`

But some file names include unicode characters, so CloudFront would return:

```
<Error>
    <Code>InvalidArgument</Code>
    <Message>
        Header value cannot be represented using ISO-8859-1.
    </Message>
    <ArgumentName>response-content-disposition</ArgumentName>
    <ArgumentValue>inline;filename=文件名 - abc.pdf</ArgumentValue>
    <RequestId>1234567890</RequestId>
    <HostId>
        123456789
    </HostId>
</Error>
```

So as many people suggested (e.g. [AWS Developer Forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=410130)), I added ***=uft-8''** in **response-content-disposition** as below:

`https://cloudfront/filekey?response-content-disposition=inline%3Bfilename%2A%3DUTF-8%27%27{utf-8-encoded-filename.pdf}&Expires=...`

Now it returns

```
<Error>
  <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
  <Message>Access denied</Message>
</Error>
```

Its **origin domain name** is in this format: `AWSDOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com`, so it's a S3 REST API endpoint.

**origin access identity (OAI)** is configured with existing identity. And I chose to manually update permissions on the S3 bucket.

In S3, objects are AES-256-encrypted. In bucket policy, there is only one statement to allow OAI access. The owner of this bucket and objects is the same account.

After reading [I’m using an S3 REST API endpoint as the origin of my CloudFront distribution. Why am I getting 403 Access Denied errors?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-rest-api-cloudfront-error-403/), I start to think maybe it's because the filename doesn't match?

The file uploaded was named **文件名 - abc.pdf**, but in s3 it's shown as **_-_abc.pdf**. But I've tried to use **_-_abc.pdf** in **response-content-disposition**, it still returns me access denied.

Comment: `AccessDenied` error is NOT related to the utf-8 encoding stuff. Could you describe how you set up the whole thing? What's the origin?

Comment: @jellycsc Thank you. I have added more details.

Comment: Try using the S3 global endpoint. `AWSDOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET.s3.amazonaws.com`

Comment: @jellycsc I tried this, but it still returns access denied..

Answer (score 0):

I finally made it work, so I think I'd better write my solution here.

When an object is uploaded to S3, its filename will be encoded, as I mentioned in the question: **文件名 - abc.pdf** -> **_-_abc.pdf**. But the filename saved in our database is still the original one, so it would return access denied as the filename is wrong.

But if I use **_-_abc.pdf** in **response-content-disposition**, it still returns access denied. Because I forgot I'm using signed URL, and it's signed based on object key and **response-content-disposition**.

So here I don't need adding utf-8 at all. And I should modify my url generation codes, instead of simply changing **response-content-disposition** in the browser.

Besides, because I'm not sure how S3 encode filenames, I directly extract filenames from object keys. Below is my codes written in Scala:

```
// r.s3ObjectKey is in format: YYYY/MM/DD/encodedFileName-digits
val fileName = r.s3ObjectKey.split("/").last.split("-").dropRight(1).mkString("-")
```